# Display of mat-icon-button together with mat-raised-button is broken in Angular Material 15

Tags: angular, angular-material

Angular v14 + Angular Material v14 (before):
[image]

After update to Angular v15 + Angular Material v15, it looks like
[image]

The code of the icon button is:

```
<button *ngIf="admin"
        class="edit-btn"
        mat-raised-button
        mat-icon-button
        color="primary"
        [routerLink]="['edit/item', item.id]"
><mat-icon>edit</mat-icon></button>
```

According to my IDE (WebStorm), the problem now is that `More than one component is matched on this element: MatButton ( button[mat-button], button[mat-raised-button], button[mat-flat-button], button[mat-stroked-button] ) and MatIconButton (button[mat-icon-button])`. The Angular CLI does not say a word.

If I only leave `mat-icon-button` attribute (without `mat-raised-button`) with v15, I get this:
[image]

which is not good.

Is the only option with Angular Material v15 to use custom styling? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I also tried to use `class="mat-raised-button mat-icon-button"`, without good results. One of the classes breaks another, and `mat-icon-button` only does not give color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you can use both mat-raised-button mat-icon-button together any more, alternatively you can use mat-mini-fab

```html
<button *ngIf="admin"
        class="edit-btn"
        mat-mini-fab
        color="primary"
        [routerLink]="['edit/item', item.id]"
><mat-icon>edit</mat-icon></button>
```

Comment: Thanks! Now the appearance is good without any need for customization!